# Zero-inflated gaussian model

Tags: r, normal-distribution, generalized-linear-model

I am trying to create a generalised linear model with random effect. I have a small dataset, with longitudinal data of 4 subjects during many years. The data I obtain from them is a frequency data, and for one of the subjects all of the data points are 0. So when checking the normality and the residual plots the distribution is not normal.

I tried transforming the data in different ways but the plot remains to look the same.

Is there any model or transformation I can use for this type of data, where one of the subjects shows no variability?

This is my model in R:

```
 m=lme(Freq ~ Time, random=~ 1|Subject,  data=my_data, method='ML')
```

Thank you

Comment: why is one subject all 0s? Did they drop out early? Is the results from a continuous measure that was consistently below a detection threshold? Or did they genuinely experience or do things with 0 frequency during the whole follow up? You would need to provide a bit more detail so readers can understand what may or may not be appropriate to recommend.

Comment: The frequency is 0 because the subject did not show at any point the behaviour we were looking for.

Comment: Frequency is a count or scaled count (a count divided by some other amount?); I'd be inclined to model the count itself.